# Read RGB from bitmap - wrong values (of RGB); c++

Tags: c++, image, bitmap, rgb

I want to read the RGB values of all pixels from a BMP file.
I have code in c++, which look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    FILE *streamIn;
    streamIn = fopen("./Untitled.bmp", "r");
    if (streamIn == (FILE *)0) {
        printf("File opening error ocurred. Exiting program.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    unsigned char info[54];
    fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, streamIn);

    int width = *(int*)&info[18];
    int height = *(int*)&info[22];

    int image[width*height][3];
    int i = 0;

    for(i=0;i<width*height;i++) {
        image[i][2] = getc(streamIn);
        image[i][1] = getc(streamIn);
        image[i][0] = getc(streamIn);
        printf("pixel %d : [%d,%d,%d]\n",i+1,image[i][0],image[i][1],image[i][2]);
    }

    fclose(streamIn);

    return 0;
}
```

and an image like this (grid overlaid):

[image: 6x12 pixels bitmap file with white and black colors - 24bit format]

which are 6x12 pixels file with two colors - black and white.

I try to find out why after executing the above code with the image as a parameter I don't get just pixels with RGB: [0,0,0] and [255,255,255] but also [0,248,0], [7,224,0] and others.

Hex dump of that file is:

```
0000-0010:  42 4d 9a 01-00 00 00 00-00 00 7a 00-00 00 6c 00  BM...... ..z...l.
0000-0020:  00 00 08 00-00 00 0c 00-00 00 01 00-18 00 00 00  ........ ........
0000-0030:  00 00 20 01-00 00 13 0b-00 00 13 0b-00 00 00 00  ........ ........
0000-0040:  00 00 00 00-00 00 42 47-52 73 00 00-00 00 00 00  ......BG Rs......
0000-0050:  00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00  ........ ........
0000-0060:  00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00  ........ ........
0000-0070:  00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 02 00-00 00 00 00  ........ ........
0000-0080:  00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 ff ff-ff ff ff ff  ........ ........
0000-0090:  ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff  ........ ........
0000-00a0:  ff ff ff ff-ff 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00  ........ ........
0000-00b0:  00 00 00 00-00 00 00 ff-ff ff ff ff-ff 00 00 00  ........ ........
0000-00c0:  00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 00 ff  ........ ........
0000-00d0:  ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff  ........ ........
0000-00e0:  ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff  ........ ........
0000-00f0:  ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff  ........ ........
0000-0100:  ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff  ........ ........
0000-0110:  ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff  ........ ........
0000-0120:  ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff  ........ ........
0000-0130:  ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff  ........ ........
0000-0140:  ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff  ........ ........
0000-0150:  ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff  ........ ........
0000-0160:  ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff  ........ ........
0000-0170:  ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff  ........ ........
0000-0180:  ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff  ........ ........
0000-0190:  ff ff 00 00-00 ff ff ff-00 00 00 ff-ff ff 00 00  ........ ........
0000-019a:  00 ff ff ff-00 00 00 ff-ff ff                    ........ ..
```

File size is 410 bytes. It should be 270 (6*12*3 + 54). That means that there is some extra information in this file.

Comment: Are you sure the format is 24 bit bmp and not a png renamed?

Comment: A BMP image 6 pixels wide will have padding after each row of pixels. (A row of pixels must contain a number of bytes that is divisible by 4, so 6x3 has two pixels of padding after each 6 pixels. You should also look at the appropiate header information to make sure that your BMP is a 24-bit RGB bitmap.

Comment: Bitmap file format isn't such easy (it depends on image format how it's written on disk). That said why 1) Why don't you use WinSDK structure for BMP? 2) It's terribly not portable (reading a byte array and accessing unaligned integers...)

Comment: For purposes of cleansiness: `using namespace` is C++, the rest of your code and tags say `C`. Which is it?

Comment: @Jongware - In this case programming language is not important. I'm working on an algorithm which parameter should be an array with RGB values of bitmap image.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I don't use WinSDK because of I don't have Windows ;)

Comment: @MarcoA. I'm sure that it is 24bit bmp - I prepared this image by myself and saved it (in gimp) as a 24bit bmp.

Comment: Very good! Getting the algorithm right is indeed more useful than the actual language in which it is written. (Also, in that case changing the language tag to the correct one does not make a difference.)

Comment: @MOehm I'm not sure if you are right. I prepare image 8x12 pixels and I also have the RGB values which I don't expect. For example: pixel 1 : [82,71,66]
pixel 2 : [0,0,115]
pixel 3 : [0,0,0]
pixel 4 : [0,0,0]

Comment: @trojek: Padding is an issue with BMP files stored as 24-bit colours; it may not be an issue in your case. I really suspect that you have a monochrome bitmap or something. Check the colour depth in the header.

Comment: Do a hex dump of the file and verify that the pixels are where you expect them to be. The integer starting at offset 10 should tell you where the pixels start.

Comment: Are you sure you're reading the pixel buffer from the right index ? Some applications adds bits of data just after the DIB (40) header, thus, making the actual pixels start at offset 52, 54, 56, 102 or 140, etc... Edit : and - while somewhat "unexpectable" - what about bitmap compression ? (RLE, DXT...)

Comment: @fsintegral I'm not sure that I'm reading the pixel buffer from the right index but I don't now how to check it. I will add a hex dump to the post - maybe it will be helpful.

Comment: Make sure you open the file in binary mode.  Note the `b` in the access mode: `fopen("./Untitled.bmp", "rb")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your *Bitmap* file consists:

**Bitmap File Header: 14 Bytes**
`42 4d 9a 01-00 00 00 00-00 00 7a 00-00 00`

The last 4 bytes is the *offset* of where rgb values begin, `7A = after 122 Bytes`

**DIB header** 
The `first 4 bytes` is the size:
`6c 00 00 00 -> 108 Bytes so BITMAPV4HEADER`

The next *8 Bytes* are the width and height in pixels:
`08 00-00 00 0c 00-00 00
 width       height each 4 Bytes`

So your bitmap is **not** `6x12` but `8x12`! There is no need for padding because 8x3 = 24 which is multiple of 4.

The actual pixels are from `0x7A - 0x199`
Beginning from the last row and going upwards, from left to right, the bitmap is:

[image]

The file size is correct:

`file size = Bitmap File Header + DIB header + rgb Bytes = 14 + 108 + 8 * 12 * 3 = 410`

To read a specific pixel in your image:

Load the whole bitmap file

```
char *buff;
char rgb[8 * 12 * 3]; //for simplicity
fptr = fopen("....bmp", "rb");

fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_END);
int file_Size = ftell(fptr);
fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET);

buff = malloc(file_Size * sizeof(char));

fread(buff, sizeof(char), file_Size, fptr);

memmove(rgb, buff[0x7A], 8 * 12 * 3);
```

Now `rgb` contains the actual pixels but the order is **left->right and down->up** meaning the first pixel is the one at the *left bottom* of the image.

Comment: You are right. I was trying different images and past not that hex dump (from image 8x12 not 6x12 pixels).